# Meteor package images are not shown on production server

Tags: node.js, meteor, production-environment, meteorite

I have added [chosen-package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/chosen-package) to my app, but when I deployed it on production, images of the package are not loaded. Example page: http://package-images.meteor.com/

How to show/load images of Meteor package on production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note to package creators:** If you include images and css which reference those images, you must modify the paths (or user an override css file) to start with `/packages`, otherwise the files won't be found in production.

I haven't used chosen but after spending a couple of minutes looking at the source it looks like it wasn't packaged in a way that will work with the current version of meteor's production path system. You have two choices:

1. Use [select2](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/select2) instead.
2. Create a new version of chosen (you could host it locally or create a new atmosphere package), and include a path override css file. See [this](https://github.com/nate-strauser/meteor-select2/blob/master/path-override.css) example from select2.