# Inaccessible font after bundle/deploy

Tags: deployment, meteor, package, bundle, font-awesome

Helo,

I've created small application:

```
  meteor create fatest
  cd fatest
```

that uses uikit-2 package from Atmosphere:

```
  mrt add uikit-2
```

When I run this application locally by command:

```
  meteor
```

font icons in list are visible, but when I deploy this application on meteor.com,
icons aren't load.
See on: http://fatest.meteor.com/

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong while minimizing the js file. I temporarily deploy without minimizing to avoid this kind of error:

```
meteor deploy --debug yoursite.meteor.com
```

Comment: You have right, now on the page: http://fatest.meteor.com is version deployed with `--debug` argument and icon fonts are visible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the css paths need to be fixed for this to work in production (this is a really common problem). See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378779/meteor-package-images-are-not-shown-on-production-server) question for more details.